# Quartz does not execute tasks according to Cron expressions

Tags: java, quartz

Recently, I am using Quartz to perform some scheduled tasks. I use SpringBoot to integrate Quartz. When I use memory storage, everything is normal. When I JDBC quartz, the tasks will not be executed according to Cron expressions. I set it to be executed once every minute, but it will actually be executed every 2 minutes or more. Has anyone encountered this situation?

SpringBoot version 2.7
Quartz Version 2.3.2

```
@Bean
public Trigger emailTrigger() {
    CronScheduleBuilder csb = CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ?");
    csb.withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing();
    return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().forJob(taskJobDetail()).withIdentity("task", "task")
            .withSchedule(csb).build();
}


@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()) + ": task");
}
```

2022-06-03 04:07:00: task

2022-06-03 04:09:00: task

2022-06-03 04:11:00: task

2022-06-03 04:13:00: task

2022-06-03 04:15:00: task

2022-06-03 04:17:00: task

2022-06-03 04:19:00: task

2022-06-03 04:21:00: task

2022-06-03 04:23:00: task

Comment: [how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

Quartz knows it does not always execute on time. The reasons can be different. Just as an example, imagine you have CronTriggers setup for more jobs at the same time than you have threads in your pool. Obviously some jobs would not get executed at all or with delay.

I cannot tell what exeactly is going on in your environment, but evidence of the above can be seen when looking at the API: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.4.0-SNAPSHOT/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getMisfireInstruction--

Comment: You are right, my thread pool is Quartz's default thread pool, there are a total of 10 threads, but my task and my trigger each have only one

Comment: I see the Trigger status of the database, it will become acquired, but the task will not be executed, and then become wating

Answer (score 0):

It does make sense under two hypothesis:

1. there is another running instance of your application (f.e. two nodes environment)
2. your job is marked as "DisallowConcurrentExecution" (or equivalent setting via quartz.config)

If so, when you run with in-memory management both nodes have no way to synchronize and they trigger every time.

When you switch to DB management, each node begins to check if another node has already executed the job and, when it is the case, it skips.